# How to edit the background color of List View elements programmatically before the list view is shown in an android app?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview, listviewitem

I'm creating an Android application using Java in Android Studio. I need to create a list view where previously selected elements will be shown as selected when the list view is recreated. Multiple elements from the list view can be selected. The list view will first be created and we will keep track of what is  saved in a list of `Pair<String, boolean>` where the `String` is the list view element and the `boolean` indicates whether or not the element was selected.

I handle the change of background color using

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
        {

            if(!tmpSelectedSkills.get(position).isSelected()){
                tmpSelectedSkills.get(position).setIsSelected(true);
                parent.getChildAt(position).setBackgroundColor(
                    Color.parseColor("#A9BCF5"));}
            else{
                tmpSelectedSkills.get(position).setIsSelected(false);
                parent.getChildAt(position).setBackgroundColor(
                        Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));}
        }
```

If the user closes the list view and choses to recreate it to change his choices I'd like to change the background color of his previous choices in the new list view before showing it to the user.

To do so I need to access the

```
View view
```

from the signature of `onItemClick`, which corresponds to the `View` of which I want to change the background color.

Comment: You handle this in your `ListAdapter`. With `ArrayAdapter`, that would be part of your `getView()` method. For a `SimpleCursorAdapter`, it might be accomplished via a `ViewBinder`. And so on.

Comment: @CommonsWare do you mean
    public abstract android.view.View getView(int position,
                                          android.view.View convertView,
                                          android.view.ViewGroup parent)

? If so I'm not sure what the convertView corresponds to here, and what the parent represents (is it the List View?)

Comment: `getView()` is `abstract` only on `BaseAdapter`. Other adapter classes (e.g., `ArrayAdapter`, `SimpleCursorAdapter`) have a concrete implementation that you can override. But, yes, that is the `getView()` method that I referenced in my earlier comment. If you do not know what `getView()` is or how it works, you have far more fundamental gaps in your knowledge that you need to address, well before you start thinking again about the problem cited in your question.

Comment: I think I see what you mean. getView() is used to recycle the views depending on which item is viewable on screen by using the unviewable view to create the new one. This means that the view I am trying to access might not exist if it is not currently shown. 

In order to change the background color of the item would I have to overwrite the getView() method to check for the selection status there and generate it with or without the background color modified?

Comment: "In order to change the background color..." -- correct. Now, depending on what you're doing here, "change the background color" could be "apply the activated state to the row via `setActivated()`" or literally "change the background color of whatever container is used for the row views". That's up to you. But the place to apply that, to a newly-created list, is in `getView()` or the equivalent (e.g., a `ViewBinder` added to `SimpleCursorAdapter`).

Answer (score 0):

You can create a method `updateData()` in your `adapter`. In the `YourObject` of `List<YourObject>` define a fields `boolean` for know selected. When you `clickOnItem` of listview, set this fields to `true` and `notifyDataChanged` by method `updateData()`. In your adapter, check if fields == true, set backgroud for row. Sorry my bad english